# Facebook Registration Plugin with RegExp

Tags: javascript, facebook

I need to validate a field in my the Facebook Registration plugin.  I need to ensure that no special characters or spaces are used on the handle field. The preg_match works great with php but not sure how do do with with Javascript.

This is what I have for my if statement.  Even when I used the proper text for the handle field it still comes up invalid.

```
var thisRegex = new RegExp('^(_|([a-z]_)|[a-z])([a-z0-9]+_?)*$/i');

                                                              if(!thisRegex.test(form.handle)){
                                                                    errors.handle = "No spaces or special characters.";
                                                                }
```

Here is the full form code:

```
                                                            {"name":"name"},

                                                            {"name":"handle",      "description":"Username - Letters & Underscores Only",             "type":"text"},

                                                            {"name":"email"},

                                                            {"name":"country",    "description":"Country",   "type":"select",    "options":{"United States":"United States","Canada":"Canada","Other":"Other"}},

                                                            {"name":"password"},

                                                            ]'
                                                          redirect-uri="http://www.mystoragelink.com"
                                                          width="320"
                                                          onvalidate="validate">
                                                        </fb:registration>

                                                        <script> 
                                                        function validate(form) {
                                                          errors = {};


                                                          var thisRegex = new RegExp('^(_|([a-z]_)|[a-z])([a-z0-9]+_?)*$/i');

                                                          if(!thisRegex.test(form.handle)){
                                                                errors.handle = "No spaces or special characters.";
                                                            }

                                                          return errors;
                                                        }
                                                        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>

<script>

function ValidateForm()

{

 var fname =document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var lname=document.getElementById('lname').value;
    var email= document.getElementById('email').value;
    var pwd=document.getElementById('pwd').value;
    //var email= document.getElementById('email');
    if(email!='')
    {

    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if (filter.test(document.getElementById('email').value)) {
   return true;
 }

 else
 {
  alert('Please provide a valid email address');

   document.getElementById('email').focus();
    return false;
 }}





      if(fname == '')
    {
    alert("plz enter your firstname");
    return false;
    }
    else if(lname == '')
    {
    alert("plz enter your lastname");
    return false;
    }
    else if(email == '')
    {
    alert("plz enter your email address");
    return false;

}
// var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
   // else if (!filter.test(document.getElementById('email').value;)) 
   // {
    // alert('Please provide a valid email address');

   // email.focus;
    // return false;

    //}
    else if(pwd == '')
    {
    alert("plz enter your password");
    return false;

     }
     }
    </script>
    </head>


<form action="login.php" method="POST">

<table border="1">
<tr>
<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"></td></tr><br>
 <tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"></td></tr><br>
<tr><td> Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td></tr><br>
<tr> <td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd">`enter code here`</td></tr><br>
 <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Insert"onclick="return ValidateForm();"></td></tr>
 </tr>
 </form>



**I think this will help You**
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your efforts.  I was able to find my problem.

in the var the last /i of the RegExp('^(*|([a-z]*)|[a-z])([a-z0-9]+_?)*$/i') needed to be removed.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Here is the working code:

```
var thisRegex = new RegExp("^(_|([a-z]_)|[a-z])([a-z0-9]+_?)*$");

                                                              if(!thisRegex.test(form.handle)){
                                                                    errors.handle = "No spaces or special characters.";
                                                                }
```